# CSV file taken through API won't print properly into individual lines

Tags: python, csv

I'm quite new to Python and am trying to learn as much as I can by watching videos/reading tutorials.

I was following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SHZjQoiJZKY&index=11&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDejNczz7dbpyu3JnwUBvNch) on how to take data from Quandl. I know there is a specific module for python already, but I wanted to learn how to take it from the website if necessary. My issue is that when I try to emulate the code around 9:50 and print the result, python doesn't split the lines in the `CSV file`. I understand he's using python 2.x, while I'm using 3.4.

Here's the code I use:

```
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen

def grabQuandl(ticker):
    endLink = 'sort_order=desc'#without authtoken

    try:
        salesRev = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/SEC/'+ticker+'_SALESREVENUENET_Q.csv?&'+endLink).read()

        print (salesRev)   

    except Exception as e:
        print ('failed the main quandl loop for reason of', str(e))

grabQuandl('AAPL')
```

And this is what gets printed:

> b'Date,Value\n2009-06-27,8337000000.0\n2009-12-26,15683000000.0\n2010-03-27,13499000000.0\n2010-06-26,15700000000.0\n2010-09-25,20343000000.0\n2010-12-25,26741000000.0\n2011-03-26,24667000000.0\n2011-06-25,28571000000.0\n2011-09-24,28270000000.0\n2011-12-31,46333000000.0\n2012-03-31,39186000000.0\n2012-06-30,35023000000.0\n2012-09-29,35966000000.0\n2012-12-29,54512000000.0\n2013-03-30,43603000000.0\n2013-06-29,35323000000.0\n2013-09-28,37472000000.0\n2013-12-28,57594000000.0\n2014-03-29,45646000000.0\n2014-06-28,37432000000.0\n2014-09-27,42123000000.0\n2014-12-27,74599000000.0\n2015-03-28,58010000000.0\n'

I get that the `\n` is some sort of line splitter, but it's not working like in the video. I've googled for possible solutions, such as doing a for loop, using `read().split()`, but at best they simply remove the \n. I can't get the output into a table like in the video. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry the import csv part was my own attempt to find a solution by trying the csv reader. I've edited it out.

Comment: So "\n" is a newline.  You can `split("\n")` and get strings of whole rows, and then get away with `split(',')` maybe to get fields.  CSV data in the wild is richer than that, though, and can do "bad, things" (which is 1 field, not 2).

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't fully understand. I get that "\n" is a new line, but what do you mean I can use split(',')? Apologies for my ignorance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.read()` gives you back a byte-string , when you directly print it, you get the result you got.You can notice the `b` at the starting before the quote, it indicates byte-string.

You should decode the string you get, before printing (or directly while using `.read()` . An example -

```
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen

def grabQuandl(ticker):
    endLink = 'sort_order=desc'#without authtoken

    try:
        salesRev = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/SEC/'+ticker+'_SALESREVENUENET_Q.csv?&'+endLink).read().decode('utf-8')

        print (salesRev)   

    except Exception as e:
        print ('failed the main quandl loop for reason of', str(e))

grabQuandl('AAPL')
```

The above decodes the returned data using `utf-8` encoding, you can use whatever encoding you want (whatever encoding the data is).

---

Example to show the print behavior -

```
>>> s = b'asd\nbcd\n'
>>> print(s)
b'asd\nbcd\n'
>>> print(s.decode('utf-8'))
asd
bcd

>>> type(s)
<class 'bytes'>
```

Comment: Ah! That does it! Thank you! So how did you know you needed to use utf-8 encoding to decode it?

Comment: The most common encoding used is `utf-8` , so it was an educated guess :) . Anyway from the data you posted above, even ascii can decode it , so it should not be a problem.

Comment: Thank you! I just did. As an aside, if I am going to use this data (such as graphing it) do I still need to decode it, or should I leave it as the original and only decode if I wish to print it?

Comment: decoding would be good, rarely any methods require byte-string as input , you may be better off keeping the decoded version, and then if you need to send it into some function that needs byte-string, using `.encode()` function to convert it back to byte-string.